# passing java program arguments from docker file

Tags: java, docker

I'm trying to pass a port to a node in cluster using Docker ENV variables like this

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY /target/ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENV my_env_var = "9100"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","$my_env_var"]
```

and running it using this command:

```
docker run -p 9140:9140 -e my_env_var=9140  readingnode
```

The problem is that the  java application does not take the value from the ENV variable, it takes the env variable it self (like as a String)

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$my_env_var"
```

I tried doing this

```
ARG port
ENV port $port
```

also didn't work.

I tried using ENTRYPOINT like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java","-jar","ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","$port"]
```

also didn't work, I got:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

I tried using CMD  instead of ENTRYPOINT like this

```
CMD ["sh","-c","java","-jar","ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","$port"]
```

got like the above

And tried

```
cmd "java -jar ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $port"
```

got an error:

> /bin/sh: 1: java -jar ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 9140: not found

Also tried

```
RUN ["java","-jar","ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","$port"]
```

i don't want to use run but it's weridly doing this:

```
 > [3/3] RUN ["java","-jar","ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","1414"]:
#7 0.604 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$port"
```

It's getting the input from the command right, but it is sending $port to the Java app. I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902445/using-variable-interpolation-in-string-in-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how I fixed it: first I changed the Java image from

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
```

to

```
FROM openjdk:8
```

I changed to ENTRYPOINT to the "non-JSON" entrypoint, i.e.

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar ReadingNode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $port
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I was struggling with it for a couple of hours.